# Use dataframe row value as key for a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe with an "Open Date" column and I need to count the business days between today and the "Open Date" value.

This step I've handled with "np.busday_count"

```py
df['Aging'] = np.busday_count(df.Date_Open.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),np.datetime64('today'))
```

Now I need to include the holidays in the calculation. But, the holidays dates vary depending on the country. The solution I've found was to create a dict of lists, with the df["Country"] as key. It turned out in something like this:

```
holidays = {'BM': [numpy.datetime64('2021-09-06')],'BO': [numpy.datetime64('2021-09-14')], 'BR': [numpy.datetime64('2021-11-30')]}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to use this dict in the holiday parameter of the "np.busday_count" function. I would like to use the value of the "Country" column from the dataframe as the key for the "holidays" dict. I've tried this (just an example):

```
df['Aging'] = np.busday_count(df.Date_Open.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),np.datetime64('today'),holidays[df.Country])
```

But it returns this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

I would like to have a solution where I don't need to calculate the date difference by looping through each row.

Answer (score 0):

`np.busday_count` is not parralelizible with respect to the holidays parameter, so you can't use it in one go, even if we fixed the dict issue.

I would first try `.apply`, maybe it will be fast enough?

```
today = np.datetime64('today')
df['Aging'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x.Date_Open, today, holidays=holidays[x.Country])
```